# How to place 4 item in one row using ng-repeat

Tags: css

I am trying to place 4 item per row. I found an example but it only doing 2 item in each row. Can someone give me hint how i can change this to place 4 item in each row. Here is the example:

```
<div class="row" style="flex-wrap: wrap">
    <div class="col col-50">1</div>
    <div class="col col-50">2</div>
    <div class="col col-50">3</div>
    <div class="col col-50">4</div>
    <div class="col col-50">5</div>
    <div class="col col-50">6</div>
    <div class="col col-50">7</div>
    <div class="col col-50">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with angular so I will remove the angular stuff and make the question simpler

Comment: I would say that you need to change everything to `col-25`

Comment: This is missing some information: What CSS classes are you applying there? How do they work? What kind of answers / technologies are acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing the classes?

If your classes work as i expect this should work:

```
<div class="row" style="flex-wrap: wrap">
    <div class="col col-25">1</div>
    <div class="col col-25">2</div>
    <div class="col col-25">3</div>
    <div class="col col-25">4</div>
    <div class="col col-25">5</div>
    <div class="col col-25">6</div>
    <div class="col col-25">7</div>
    <div class="col col-25">8</div>
</div>
```